# how to show data in listviews with different buttons

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I am making an app which saves grades from students to a database. 
Now, I want to make different listviews, dependent on the button I click on. 
So, for example, there is an activity with 8 buttons (1 button for each class (not a Java class, but classes where students go to)). I made a ListView which shows data from a SQLitedatabase, but now it only shows all Students in the database. But I don't see how I can let the app show students only from a specific class.

So there is an Activity with 8 buttons (Class 1, Class 2 etc) and with a click on one of the buttons I want to show a Listview with students from that specific class.

Also, I have another problem. The app has an overview of students (with ListView) and with a click on one of the students you go to a activity where a teacher can grade the student. The app must save the grade to the database. But how can I let the app save the grade for that specific student, which is selected in a previous activity?

If you can tell me the steps I have to take to archieve this, that would be great. I researched a lot, but is so overwhelming I do not know anymore what to use.

Thanks!!

Comment: First of all to get students for each class you have to make a query to the database to select the students for that class. So when you click a button you call the function that makes the query to the database with the specific class. example String query="Select * from STUDENTS_TABLE WHERE students.class=?"; and then make a cursor = database.rawQuery(query,new String[]{className}

Comment: It will be good if you can show as schematically, instead of explanation, because the flow is what we are looking in this case. Just a rough sketch.

Comment: Okay, i will try: Loginscreen -> Startscreen -> Button 1: Overview classes - Button 2: Overview Students (which shows all students) -> If clicked on Button 1: Buttons with al the 8 classes - If clicked on Button 2: Listview with all Students -> Click on a class or student -> When you first clicked on a class, the students of the specific class will appear -> click on a student -> screen where teacher can grade a student and save to a database

Answer (score 0):

You have many way to do it.

If you click on a button, then you can ask your database for students in this class, change the content of the adapter and call *notifyDataSetChanged()*.

Or you can put all your students in your adapter at the starts and then use the Filter from ListView. Your adapter have to implements *Filterable* class and you can create a filter for your student.

Now when you click on a row, you can start an activity with an intent and set the ID of the student in it. In the Activity, just ask your database an instance of the student with this ID.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps, may be it will help you.

1. Your first screen (SCREEN 1) which contains 8 buttons (1 to 8).
2. You have another screen (SCREEN 2) on which you have a list (listview) of students.
3. Assuming your database has all students records. (From class 1st to 8th).
4. You SCREEN 1 contains click listener for each button.
5. When you clicked any button, pass that button value (e.g. You clicked 7th) to next screen with the help of bundles & intents. (pass value from SCREEN 1 to SCREEN 2)
6. You will get clicked button value on next SCREEN 2 (7th)
7. Now with help of that value fetch only that value data from database (7th class students)
8. Set fetched data to SCREEN 2's Listview.